# What does it mean for a matrix to wedge product itself? (Cartan's second structural equation)

Tags: tensor-products

In page-440 of Tristan Needham's Visual Differential geometry, the following equation is given:

$$ d \left[ \omega \right] = \left[ \omega \right] \wedge \left[\omega \right]$$

Where $\left[ \omega \right]$ is a matrix and $d$ is the exterior derivative. The exterior derivative here is defined to act on the matrix by individually taking exterior derivative of it's entries.

What I fail to understand is **what does it mean to take a wedge product of two matrices** in linear algebra notation?  For reference, early on , the wedge product was introduced as anti symmetric part of the tensor product.

Comment: Suppose $A, B$ are matrices of appropriate size such that their product in the usual linear algebra sense is defined. Now suppose instead the entries of $A, B$, rather than real or complex numbers, are differential forms (suppose $A$ has k-forms and $B$ has $l$-forms). Then $A\wedge B$ means the matrix of $(k+l)$-forms obtained by performing the usual linear algebra product of matrices with all instances of scalar multiplication ($\cdot$) replaced by wedge products.

Comment: Ohhhhhh lol didn't think it'd be that simple. Could you write an answer, I'll accept it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just replace scalar multiplication in the usual matrix multiplication by wedge products. So, if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of $p$-forms and $B$ is an $n\times k$ matrix of $q$-forms, then $A\wedge B$ is an $m\times k$ matrix of $(p+q)$-forms whose entries are (for all $i\in\{1,\dots m\},j\in\{1,\dots, k\}$)
\begin{align}
(A\wedge B)_{ij}&=\sum_{l=1}^nA_{il}\wedge B_{lj}.
\end{align}

Even more generally, suppose you have sets $G_1,G_2,G_3$, where $G_3$ is an abelian group and that the elements of $A$ belong to $G_1$, the elements of $B$ belong to $G_2$, and you have a mapping $*:G_1\times G_2\to G_3$. Then, you can define $A*B$ as the matrix with elements in $G_3$ using the same formula (replace $\wedge$ with $*$ everywhere above).