# Explicit computation of structural equations of Maurer-Cartan forms for a matrix group

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

In *Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability* by Luis A. Santalo and Mark Kac, on page 154, the authors compute an explicit form of the Maurer-Cartan structure equations for a given matrix group.

[image]

My question is, how is the wedge product matrix-valued of differential forms $\Omega \wedge \Omega$ computed here?

Comment: Tensors are generalized matrices. $a_{ij}$-entry is coefficient of $dx_i\otimes dx_j$. Can you construct forms from tensors?

Comment: Multiply the matrices, inserting a wedge product between elements of the first matrix and elements of the second matrix.

Comment: We have $\Omega =\sum_{i=1}^3 A_i\,\omega_i$ for suitable $3\times3$-matrices; e.g. $A_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$. Then $\Omega\wedge\Omega:=\sum_{i,j} A_i A_j\,\omega_i\wedge\omega_j=\sum_{i<j}[A_i, A_j]\,\omega_i\wedge\omega_j$.

Comment: See [What does it mean for a matrix to wedge product itself? (Cartan's second structural equation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4438970/568204).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Just a heads up to future readers that may come across confusing situations like I did, be careful in which vector spaces your forms are valued, because $\omega_i \wedge \omega_i$ may not be $0$!

Comment: But in the notation of that book in this instance, yes, $\omega_i$ are regular $\Bbb R$-valued $1$-forms and $\omega_i\wedge\omega_i=0$. But of course $\Omega\wedge\Omega$ need not be $0$.

Comment: Yes! The other example I came across was a matrix of Lie algebra valued differential forms. In that case, in the entries, $\omega_i \wedge \omega_i$ may not be $0$. Sometimes authors disambiguate by writing $\left[\omega_i \wedge \omega_i \right]$, which I find less confusing.